# App Name appearing above the Toolbar in Android SDK v22

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

Yesterday I updated my SDK manager with the recent launch of Android 5.1 (API 22) updates and was trying to use Material Design themes. While creating activity_main.xml layout, I found that App name (title) is appearing above the Toolbar of the screen (link to the screenshot is added below). And when I tried to preview it under Android 5.0.1 (API 21) it is working normally.
Is there anything Google new introduced, that I don't know yet, in Android 5.1 (API 22) upgrade?

The screenshot:

[image]

Do I need to share the code?

style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Are you using a theme with `NoActionBar`? I am thinking that an ActionBar as well as the ToolBar are both being shown here.

Comment: It's fine. It's just a static depiction. The display has  no clue that the toolbar will become your action bar or whatever

Comment: yes, check my Q again, i have added the styles.xml code that shows my theme

Comment: Little Child, is this Android Studio error? coz I tried to run my app on both, pre-Lollipop and Lollipop, devices and it is working fine (not showing App name).

Comment: @aB9: And you have assigned the same Theme to your Activity / Application? Do you get same result when you run the app on your device / emulator?

Comment: @aB9 You have to tag them so they see your comment response just like I tagged you here

Comment: @SiddharthLele , no. App shows a normal screen (without app name above toolbar)

Comment: @aB9: Then it's just the preview in Studio that's showing it wrong? That's a little strange because on my Studio it shows just fine. Try this: change the theme from the dropdown and select your theme.

Comment: @SiddharthLele i tried as you suggested but no effect, it is still showing the same. I guess it the preview screen of Android Studio which is messing the scene.

Comment: @aB9: Perhaps it's just Studio messing up the preview. Update Studio if you haven't already. That's the best I can think of. :-(

Comment: @SiddharthLele, yes! Found that Android Studio 1.2 Preview is available to install on Android Tools Project site. ( I use 1.1 version which is official)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** : This is not error from Android Studio,You should put styles.xml in values-v21 and the app name will not appear as the following screen shot.

[image]

Comment: I know that, when I first tried it worked fine, but I was confused when I saw this thing for the 1st time in android studio's preview window. Thought something is wrong with my edition of studio

Comment: sorry about that.. it's not error from android studio , you should add style.xml for values-v21 .. try and test it again ..it will work fine

Comment: Did that, its because of api 22 only. Read above comments. Hope they will get a solution over it

Comment: i also tested it in api 22 and not appeared ! .. so what is the problem ?

Comment: But my edition is showing this error. For now I keep it at api 21. I also tried using next version of android studio ( unofficial, beta version), still hv that error

Comment: may be in older version of android studio, i use android studio v 1.1.0 , i also add screen shot :)